# Applescript and SpeechRecognitionServer: reading in a file as "listen for"

Tags: applescript

In place of the list in

```
tell app "SpeechRecognitionServer to set theQueryList to listen for {"list item 1", "list item 2"...}
```

I'd like to read in a text file that contains the list. Something like

```
set theQueryList to read POSIX file "/Users/username/folder/text.txt"
```

The file text.txt contains a list, written out as

```
"list item 1", "list item 2", ... "list item n"
```

**without brackets** and in utf8 (I hope) format. (I created the file by cat'ing it in Terminal.)

This works, somewhat. I mean: I can display the list from text.txt  in a dialog, and I can use it in a repeat loop. But it doesn't trigger SpeechRecognitionServer when spoken. (I don't know a better way to say this.) I should mention that when I paste the list from this file into the script, it works fine. So the list items don't seem to be at fault -- nor how I say them.

Apologies if I'm a bit fuzzy in my wording here. Grateful for your ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Your file will need to have the data encoded as an actual _list_, or if it is just plain text, you will need to do something to convert it to a _list_, such as getting lines/paragraphs or splitting the text using AppleScript's text item delimiters.

Comment: Thanks. It's comma separated, no brackets, no quotation marks. When I include brackets and/or quotation marks, the script timesout -- or returns a -1708 error, which I thought at first had to do with having the file read into the SpeechRecognitionServer tell block, so I moved the read statement up (Script editor owns it) and passed the contents of the file down the line in a variable. Interesting to note that when I make the file one item long, it works like a charm. It's been quite a few years since I've had my head in this stuff; I'm grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items to listen for need to be in a *list*, so you will need to extract the items from the text.

If the items in the text are separated by end-of-ine characters:

```
list item 1
list item 2
list item 3
list item n
```

you can just get the paragraphs:

```
set theQueryList to paragraphs of (read POSIX file "/Users/username/folder/text.txt")
```

If the items in the text are separated by commas (or tabs, or whatever):

```
list item 1,list item 2,list item 3,list item n
```

you can use AppleScript's `text item delimiters`:

```
set separator to "," -- the separating text
set fileText to (read POSIX file "/Users/username/folder/text.txt")
set {tempTID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, separator}
set theQueryList to text items of fileText
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tempTID -- restore original
```

Comment: Brilliant. I'm grateful. Truly.